# JNLP does not load prolog file

Tags: java, java-web-start

I made a Java Web Start applications and it works just fine except the fact that when i click the "continue" button  it doesn't load the new.pl file as i should be..
In java i use this code

```
 Term consult_arg[] = {
            new Atom("C://Users//dmpasd//Documents//NetBeansProjects//Anemia//src//anemia//new.pl")
        };
        Query consult_query
                = new Query(
                        "consult",
                        consult_arg);

        boolean consulted = consult_query.hasSolution();

        if (!consulted) {
            System.err.println("Consult failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

When i run it from netbeans it works but in JWS it doesn't.

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: It shows the gui i made but in the end when i clicked the button that is for consulting a prolog file it did n't load the file..

Comment: Oops...i think i find the problem.....all works fine..i had wrong path in file... The only problem now is the self signed.. Is there anyone know how to sign a specified key?

Comment: *"The only problem now is the self signed.."*  The only solution is to buy a code signing certificate.